# 64-bit JVM on Server, 32-bit JVM on Client, combination possible?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

I'm having a JBoss EJB3 Application and a Swing client, running in 32-bit Java 6 VM's. We now have to change the Server JVM to 64 bit. May this combination of JVM's cause any trouble (do I need to use 64-bit JVM on the client, too)?

Greetings,

buzztee

Answer (score 4):

No trouble with the combination. Anyway, its good practice to declare **serialversionUID** on your transmitted, serializable classes.

Answer (score 1):

Will it cause any problems? No.